# sql incorrect syntax near '.' when trying to use ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I try to insert into my table's database I receive 
an **SqlException** pointing on the following code :

```
int x = 0;
{
   connect.Open(); //connect is an SqlConnection object
   x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

the error points at the line where :

```
x = command.ExecuteNoneQuery;
```

saying that :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

here is the partial c# code: (the part which is relevant)

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\thkiw\OneDrive\Documents\ilan.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO profiles(userName , name , lastName , password , birthYear , birthMonth , birthDay , gender , email)" +
                                        "VALUES(" + user_name + "," + name  +"," + last_name + "," + password + "," + 
                                        year +","+ "," + month + "," + "day" + "," +
                                        (gender ? "1": "0")  +","+email + ")"

                                        , connect);                                   //GENDER is bit so 1 -true , 0 - false; (gender doesn't seem to convert automatically...)
    int x = 0;

    //try
    {
        connect.Open();
        x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    /*catch (SqlException exception)
    {
        Session["lastException"] = exception;
        Session["source"] = "register.aspx";

        Response.Redirect("handleExceptions.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Session["lastException"] = exception;
        Session["source"] = "register.aspx";

        Response.Redirect("handleExceptions.aspx");
    }*/
    connect.Close();

    Response.Write("SUCCESS  - number of rows affected : " + x);
```

And this is the table schema

here is the table's code : (profiles)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[profiles] (
[userName]   NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
[name]       NCHAR (10) NULL,
[lastName]   NCHAR (10) NULL,
[birthDay]   INT        NULL,
[birthMonth] INT        NULL,
[birthYear]  INT        NULL,
[password]   NCHAR (15) NULL,
[gender]     BIT        NOT NULL,
[email]      NCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userName] ASC)
);
```

Comment: There's an issue `year +","+ "," + month + ","` here; too many commas?  Try `year +"," + month + ","` instead.

Comment: You really need to use parameters, not only to avoid sql injection, but to help avoid issues where you forget to put single quotes around strings or correctly format a date, or make it harder to see two consecutive commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you should handle inserting data into a query with parameters

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO profiles(userName, name, lastName, password, birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay, gender, email)" +
    "VALUES(@userName, @name, @lastName, @password, @birthYear, @birthMonth, @birthDay, @gender, @email)"
    , connect);
command.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = user_name;
command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = name;
command.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = last_name;
command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = password;
command.Parameters.Add("@birthYear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = year;
command.Parameters.Add("@birthMonth", SqlDbType.Int).Value = month;
command.Parameters.Add("@birthDay", SqlDbType.Int).Value = day;
command.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = gender;
command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = email;
```

This will avoid sql injection and handle formatting issues like the format of a `DateTime` or needing single quotes around a `varchar` value.  Additionally it makes the query much cleaner and easier to spot issues like the two consecutive commas you have between the month and year.

Comment: Nice solution, but, you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I have recovered the deleted table and not sure if you can write a string in a BIT field.

Comment: @Steve Yeah, I've fixed that to set the correct type and just set it with `gender` since it is a `bool`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Really, how so?  It fixes the issue of needing single quotes around the string values and the consecutive commas.

Comment: Yes, but you never explained why the original code was failing, which was the question. It wasn't just single-quotes. Or, at least you don't make that problem obvious.  It's a good solution, I recommend it too, but the answer should come first and suggested improvements, second.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I mentioned that this takes out the need to put in single quotes and it make it easier to spot issues like the double commas.  And using paramters instead of concatenating a query is a solution and not just a suggestion because those changes to the current approach will also stop working as soon as they get someone with a last name like O'Neil.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't enclose your values in single quotes.

However the best way is to use SQL Parameters. This prevents issues like this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

This eliminates issues like this among other things like SQL injection. This is best practice.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user_name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", last_name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender ? "1" : "0");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO profiles(userName , name , lastName , password , birthYear , birthMonth , birthDay , gender , email) VALUES(@userName , @name , @lastName , @password , @birthYear , @birthMonth , @birthDay , @gender , @email)", connect);
```

Comment: Very true, but this would be better suited as a comment unless you're going to show the OP how they would change their code to use parameters.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the feedback. Fixed

Comment: Nice solution, but, you didn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ExecuteNonQuery`, you are invoking the command's `commandText`, which in your case was:

```
("INSERT INTO profiles(userName , name , lastName , password , birthYear , birthMonth , birthDay , gender , email)" +
                                        "VALUES(" + user_name + "," + name  +"," + last_name + "," + password + "," + 
                                        year +","+ "," + month + "," + "day" + "," +
                                        (gender ? "1": "0")  +","+email + ")"

                                        , connect);
```

The error indicates that your query could not be processed because you have an error in the command. And, in that command, you have:

```
year +","+ "," + month +
```

Which has two commas being inserted in a row. It should be:

```
year + "," + month +
```

To avoid this string concatenation hell, you should really use [SqlCommandParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) objects to configure your command. It also provides built-in protection against SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Damn just before me ;)

Comment: They likely also need to put single quotes around some of the other values.

Answer (score -2):

Change sql command by below:

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO profiles(userName , name , lastName , password , birthYear , birthMonth , birthDay , gender , email)" +
                                        "VALUES('" + user_name + "','" + name  +"','" + last_name + '","' + password + "'," + 
                                        year +","+ "," + month + "," + "day" + "," +
                                        (gender ? "1": "0")  +",'"+email + "')"

```
                                    , connect);
```

You forgot to add single quote both side in a character data like 'username'

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, promoting to solve this problem using string concatenation is more harmuful than useful

Comment: Yes string concatenation is harmful. But I just resolved his error. He did not asked good approach for it.

Comment: Actually this still has the double comma issue between the year and month.